# Is exexPopulate() method is deprecated from the mongoose new version?

Tags: mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate, mongoose-plugins

```
main()

    const main = async () =>{
    const task = await Task.findById('614ac31e103d9c5329d38686')
    await task.populate('owner').execPopulate()
    console.log(task.owner)
}
```

execPopulate() is not a function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From changelogs at https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html#removed-execpopulate,

the line should be replaced to

```js
await task.populate('owner')
```

Answer (score 0):

execPopulate() has been removed in latest version of mongoose , the code can only work if using oder version which is not advisable due to deprecation

Just remove the execPopulate and keep task.populate('owner')